# Docker dotnet restore "Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json."

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I added docker support(Windows) in visual studio to an asp.net core project. It runs fine in debug mode. But shows the error as below when in "Release" mode. I've tried switching to a different network (Hotspot over 4G) but still shows the same error message.

Below is the generated docker file.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-nanoserver-1809 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-nanoserver-1809 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["BlankSite/BlankSite.csproj", "BlankSite/"]
RUN dotnet restore "BlankSite/BlankSite.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/BlankSite"
RUN dotnet build "BlankSite.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "BlankSite.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BlankSite.dll"]
```

Error Message:

```
>Step 7/18 : RUN dotnet restore "BlankSite/BlankSite.csproj"
1> ---> a406dac3ca1d
1> ---> Running in 38089ed5e181
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.300\NuGet.targets(121,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [C:\src\BlankSite\BlankSite.csproj]
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.300\NuGet.targets(121,5): error :   No such host is known [C:\src\BlankSite\BlankSite.csproj]
1>The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore "BlankSite/BlankSite.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
1>C:\Users\vincentliao\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.7.9\build\Container.targets(196,5): error CTP1001: An error occurred while attempting to build Docker image.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your container does not have internet access. To fixe that, follow [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1130898/no-internet-connection-inside-docker-containers). In the case that you don't need the internet access, you can set a private repository instead of nuget.org.